# Zero potential inside and on boundary

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, potential

In Griffiths introduction to Electrodynamics, the classic image problem is presented: There is a charge q, above a grounded conducting plane.

The boundary conditions are therefore:
1.V=0, at plane
2.v=0 at infinity

My question is, since potentials are harmonic functions and the potential is zero both inside and on boundary, shouldn't the potential therefore be zero everywhere in R^3 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No, because the potential in this case in not an harmonic function.**

Your statement was correct if the differential equation you have had to solve was the Laplace's equation
$$\nabla^2V=0$$
which accounts for space without charges. In that case the potential was indeed an harmonic function, and in order to satisfy the maximum principle - it must have vanish identically.

However, in your particular case there are charges in the volume of interest, and thus one needs to fulfill the Poisson's equation
$$\nabla^{2}V=-\frac{Q}{\varepsilon_{0}}\delta\left(x\right)\delta\left(y\right)\delta\left(z-d\right)$$
in the upper half part of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$. Here I assumed the charge $Q$ is placed at $\vec{r}=\left(0,0,d\right)$. Therefore, the function is not harmonic and the maximum principle is not applicable.

Comment: But in that case, the potential reaches a local maximum inside the boundary.

Comment: In the case of the image problem? The potential is zero inside the boundary (conducting plate) as you stated.

Comment: At the boundary at infinity, the potential is zero, so how can the potential be nonzero inside this boundary since potentials are harmonic functions

Comment: Simply because the potential is not an harmonic function - due to charges in the region of interest. Thus its maximum doesn't need to be in the boundaries. I will edit my answer to stress that.